# Unable to exclude directory with yapf

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, yapf

I'm unable to exclude a directory from being autoformatted with yapf.

Tested usages:

```
yapf --in-place --recursive --parallel --exclude 'somedir' --exclude '*_pb2.py' .
yapf --in-place --recursive --parallel --exclude 'somedir/*' --exclude '*_pb2.py' .
yapf --in-place --recursive --parallel --exclude 'somedir/**' --exclude '*_pb2.py' .
```

It seems to take file patterns well but not folder patterns.

- yapf version: 0.21.0
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- python version: 2.7 (in a virtualenv)

Answer (score 5):

Did you try `yapf --in-place --recursive --parallel --exclude 'somedir/**/*.py' --exclude '**/*_pb2.py' .`?

[yapf uses `fnmatch.fnmatch(path, exclude_pattern)` under the hood](https://github.com/google/yapf/blob/32afb3004e0967eab351ee83e3d9d55e3a02fd9b/yapf/yapflib/file_resources.py#L154).